# how to filter only integer value from listbox in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have created one table which is products and then to gave only integer value ie product id below linq query using here:
var Autolist = db.Products.Select(p => p.Pid).Distinct().ToList();
listbox1.Itemsource=Autolist;
so if i am typing integer value in textbox to filtering to match shows up from listbox so how to do?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the original list in a separate one. In your case: Products.
Create a ObservableCollection of Products (FilteredProducts) and bind this one to the list.
Bind the TextBox to let's say a ProductId and set the delay to some milis:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding  ProductId                           
                         Delay=300, 
                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

As soon youthe value is set (filter for number before setting), clear the OnbservableCollection and add the values to it again.

```
FilteredProducts.Clear();

foreach(Product p in db.Products.Where(p.Id == ProductId))
{
  FilteredProducts.Add(p);
}
```

Note that:

```
listbox1.Itemsource=FilteredProducts
```

Please note that this solution is ok for small lists, if you have a huge list of items, clearing and adding items will be a problem.